# Updating text box from subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the main form "MForm" with 2 subforms "subform1" and "subform2".

On subform1 i have 5 tabbed pages: Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4, Page5. Each tab will have a subfom included.

On Page1 i have a form "subform3".

My question is, how i can update a text box "txt_test" from subform3 from subform2?

I tried:

```
Forms!MForm!subform1.Form!subform2.Form!txt_test.Value

Forms!MForm!subform1!Tab.Pages("Page1").txt_test.Value
```

I am new to access and i can't find a way to access the data from other subforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Forms!mform!subform2!txt_test.Value = Me.txt_test3.Value
```

*txt_test3* is the textbox in subform3 (on Page 1 of subform1).

Answer (score 0):

IF you put code into module of form `subform3` then this code should change value of `txt_test` inside `subform2`:

```
Me.parent.subform2.form.controls("txt_test").Value = "some value"
```

Comment: In the module of subform3, 'me.parent' will give you subform1 (the one with the pages), you need to go another level higher to get to MForm (the main form) which contains subform2.